# Can the plotly.io.write_html be used to also plot images?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, plotly, image-recognition

Usually, we use the line to plot graphs and confusion matrices. However, the official documentation doesn't really specify which types of figures are supported.
Can I actually use it for image files?
(I tried using it but it doesn't run properly, I don't know whether it was because of it not supporting it)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, it supports a `fig` meaning a plotly [figure object](https://plotly.com/python/figure-structure/).

Unless you create a plotly figure object containing your image, you won't be able to use `plotly.io.write_html(fig, ...)`

Comment: I did create a figure containing the image with go.Figure:
(If you meant that)

Comment: Can you include any code you've written in your question? That will help us debug the issue more easily